# Fetchmail: Deliver to local mailboxes based on "To" Address

Tags: postfix

I have fetchmail installed and configured to get mail from my email server.

```
poll mail.domain.com
    protocol imap
    username "email@domain.com"
    password "password"
    options ssl
```

I have one mailbox on my email server that receives mail from three different departments and I need to sort that mail with fetchmail.  The "To" header field is what I can use to filter the messages, since the mail is being sent to the specific departments but I only have one login to the actual mail server.

```
department1@domain.com -> email@domain.com
department2@domain.com -> email@domain.com
department3@domain.com -> email@domain.com

fetchmail gets email@domain.com

email@domain.com "To: department1@domain.com" -> postfix alias 1
email@domain.com "To: department2@domain.com" -> postfix alias 2
email@domain.com "To: department3@domain.com" -> postfix alias 3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Using fetchmail seems like a convoluted way of doing this. Can you explain what led you to use fetchmail over something more straightforward and standard like using virtual users in postfix?

Comment: I set up fetchmail because I wasn't able to get postfix to get the email from the mail server

Comment: Got it, I see now that you're not running fetchmail on mail.domain.com but on another system. The postfix tag was confusing me, so this is really a fetchmail question more than a postfix question.

Comment: Yes it's a fetchmail question but there's no fetchmail tag and I don't have enough reputation to create one!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest combining fetchmail with procmail. In your fetchmail poll statement, add:

```
mda procmail department_mail_sort.rc
```

Then in the *department_mail_sort.rc* file you can define how to sort and deliver the mail.

```
:0
* ^TO_department1@domain.com
!deptartment1_mailbox@localhost

:0
* ^TO_department2@domain.com
!deptartment2_mailbox@localhost

:0:
* ^TO_department3@domain.com
department3_local_mbox_file
```

Procmail has several options for delivery so definitely check out the **procmailrc** man page. It sounds like you are running a local mta in which case the ! and @localhost will pass the message there but you can also forward elsewhere, write to an mbox file like the last example, or even use a pipe to run a custom program to handle each message.